# Hide plugins and comments in custom type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a custom post type in Wordpress as follow:

```
function magazine_custom_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Magazines Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Magazine Type', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Revista', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Revista padre:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Todos las revistas', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Ver revista', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Agregar revista', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Agregar nuevo', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Modificar', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Actualizar', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Buscar', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'No encontrado', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No encontrado en la papelera', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'magazine_post_type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Magazine Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'fa fa-thumb-tack',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'magazine_post_type', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'magazine_custom_type', 0 );
```

I also created a `single-magazine_custom_type` that acts as a template for this post type but since it's a post type then some plugins are displayed there and also `Facebook Comment` box which I don't want. Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the problem of the most plugins.

You only can check if the plugin provided settings or filter/hooks for that. Check out the `readme.txt` or check out the Plugin FAQ on wordpress.org

If you cant solve the problem, you must use an another plugin.

**edit** Check out if your plugin hooks `the_content`, you can try to use `print get_the_content()`

Comment: How did I know if the plugin support what you tell me? [This is](http://peadig.com/wordpress-plugins/facebook-comments/) the plugin site and I can't find nothing helpful also `readme.txt` file isn't helpful either. Where I should test that code? In the template?

Comment: yep in your template file. You can only find relevant informations in the plugin code if you  have experience with hooks and filters, in the plugin development or generally wp-core experiences. As WordPress newbie its really hard. Currently i cant download the plugin to check that, im online with my iPhone.

Comment: Could you give me some help later? When you can in a PC?

Comment: Im going in the next hrs to my company. Yet we have 7 PM. I think im online after 9/10 PM.

Comment: Hmmm here is 1:20PM which hour is where you are? Just to take in account for the time you'll be online

Comment: Im come from germany :) I will going under the shower and make me then ready

Comment: Are you sure that you mean that plugin? I've checked this. The Facebook Comments will only displayed if you using the Shortcode `[fbcomments]` in the content...

Comment: It has a administration side and just by activating the plugin it appears

Comment: The method `fbcommentbox()` inside the `class-frontend.php` makes it autimatically. This plugin has no actions or filters for that. You can only try to remove the filter in your `Template File`. Try to add `remove_filter('the_content', 'fbcommentbox', 100);` before or after `wp_head()`